# Assembly sp and bp registers

Tags: assembly, stack, osdev

I need some help understanding how the stack registers work in x86 Assembly. The code snippets below are from a bootloader that I am studying.

The print function takes three "arguments". Since I push all three to the stack, I expect `sp` to be at `0xfff9`. `bp` takes the same address in once in the print function.

How come I have to do `[bp+4]` instead of `[bp+2]`? Since aren't the variables I pushed at locations `0xfffd` , `0xfffb` , and `0xfff9`? Then when I return from the print function I add `add sp, 6` to restore sp to same location before printing.

```
; stack initialization
mov ax, 0x0000
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0xffff
mov bp, 0xffff
```

**EDIT** Forgot about the function return address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BP points to where the previous BP value was pushed
BP + 2 points to the return address pushed by `call PRINTMESSAGE`
BP + 4 points to the last argument pushed
and so on
```